# Iphone4 crashes ipod app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I created a sample application for the iPod and it works well. I checked it lots of times on the iPod.  I installed that application onto the iPhone4.  It doesn't work - it crashed several times. I dont know why.  I have the latest iphone sdk, 3.2.

(I use sqlite3 to store and retrive data)

Comment: The latest iPhone SDK isn't version 3.2, its version 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version is *not* 3.2. You should probably upgrade to the latest version of the SDK, version 4.0.